# Wixtoolset - lock appears after installing

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

I made an msi with wixtoolset and I give permissions to the installed files to all users with the code below. The problem is that after installing, all the files on the screen appear with a lock on them. I still have permission to access them but I would like to avoid the lock thing.

My Wix version is 3.5

I know the problem is with the permissions I give because when I remove them from the instakker, the lock does not appear.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDERSERVICE">
  <!--  SERVICE FILES   -->
  <!-- Create a single component which is the TestService.exe file -->
  <Component Id="SERVICE" GUID="*">

    <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
    <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />

    <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
    <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Name="SERVICEtoINSTALL"
        DisplayName="$(var.Name)"
        Description=""
        Start="auto"
        ErrorControl="normal" />

    <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->

    <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="SERVICEtoINSTALL" Wait="yes" />

    <CreateFolder>
      <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
    </CreateFolder>

  </Component>
```

the code compiles perfectlly. I need that permissions to manage the files from other app but I would like to avoid the lock thing.
You can see it here;

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z6zYEt444DjOXe2ODP60q2X00Xpq5bkZ

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The problem was that I was giving permissions to folder of the shortcut on Desktop, removing that permission tag solved my problem!